# Insert query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table contains ~2M rows. It has B-tree primary key on (id,round), and 2 other (seems irrelevant) indexes.

My questions is:

```
insert into a1
select * from cars
where (id, round) in (select id, min(round) from cars group by id)
```

The above query will take ~30s to run
but why the following query

```
insert into a1
select * from cars
where (id, round) in (select id, max(round) from cars group by id)
```

seems to take forever to run? I've waited hours. The only thing I changed is min->max

PS: here's the create table

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `miles` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `round` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`round`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `make` (`make`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Why is the subquery grouping by `round`, rather than `id`?  You're aware that `id` in that case will be arbitrary -- right?

Comment: Try to `explain extended select * from cars where (id round) in (select id, min(round) from cars group by round)` and `explain extended select * from cars where (id round) in (select id, max(round) from cars group by round)`

Comment: select id, min(round) from cars group by id is fast while select id, max(round) from cars group by id takes forever. I tried to explain them, there is only a small difference btw "rows" ~130k v.s. ~160k

Comment: Something doesn't seem right. The `id` column isn't an auto_increment, so are you populating this with an arbitrary value? Are there multiple rows with the same `id` but differing values of `round`?

Comment: id is not auto_increment. roughly each id will correspond to ~20 rounds. so yea, there are multiples rows with same id but different rounds (~20). @mike purcell

Comment: So you are not looking for a specific id, you are looking for a max(round), why not add that to the SELECT clause instead of the WHERE clause? Try `SELECT id, make, miles, time, max(round) as max_round, location FROM cars GROUP BY id`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. two reasons: first, select id, max(round) is the main problem.. dont know why it's taking forever. second, it doesn't work..you can't select id, make... max(round) group by id, (id itself is not primary key)

Comment: @Mike: That would not produce correct results. It would show random values for columns `make`, `miles`, etc. (other than `id` and `round`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` subqueries are not optimized in the best way by current MySQL query optimizer.

I would use:

```
INSERT INTO a1
  SELECT c.* 
  FROM 
        cars AS c
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT id, MAX(round) AS round
          FROM cars 
          GROUP BY id
        ) AS m
      ON  (m.id, m.round) = (c.id, c.round)
```

The index you already have on `(id, round)` will make the subquery run pretty fast and only once (as a derived table). The other way, with the `IN`, the subquery is run once for every row of the `cars` table (that's why it's slow). Check the execution plans with `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a single index on the id field
you use the single field in your "group by" method

Comment: He already has an index on `(id, round)`. This can be used by the `GROUP BY`.